Torah’s use of the same verb(s) with different meanings
Bemidbar 1:49 tells Moshe not to פקד the Leviim, nor to תשא them, both understood as referring to methods of counting.
But then in 1:50 the same two verbs are used: the Leviim are to be “appointed”/הפקד and “will carry”/ישאו parts of the Mishkan.
Does anyone comment specifically about the Torah’s use of the same shorashim (in consecutive verses no less) with opposite
results?
(One imagines that the Torah did not lack other terminology to convey one or the other idea.)

This is a common feature in all languages, Lashon Hakodesh included.
